# How to execute Edit on MVC keeping some value unique?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to edit in MVC ,i waana change other property like name,address but keeping unique email, contract that i have created before
the model class is given below....

```
 public class Student
```

{

```
[Required]
public int StudentId { get; set; }
[Required]
[DisplayName("Name")]
public string StudentName { get; set; }
[Required]
[DisplayName("Email")]
[Remote("IsEmailUnique", "Student", ErrorMessage = "This email already exists")]
[RegularExpression(@"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address")]
public string StudentEmail { get; set; }
[Required]
[DisplayName("Contact No.")]
[RegularExpression("^(?!0+$)(\\+\\d{1,3}[- ]?)?(?!0+$)\\d{11,15}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid phone no.")]
[Remote("IsContractNoUniue", "Student", ErrorMessage = "This Reg.No already exists")]
public string StudentContactNo { get; set; }
[Required]
[DisplayName("Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

public DateTime RegistrationDate
{
    get { return (defaultDate == DateTime.MinValue) ? DateTime.Now : defaultDate; }
    set { defaultDate = value; }
}

public string Address { get; set; }
[Required]
public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
[Required]
[DisplayName("Reg.No")]
[Remote("IsRegNoUnique", "Student", ErrorMessage = "This Reg.No already exists")]
public string StudentRegistrationNumber { get; set; }

public Department Department { get; set; }
public List<StudentEnrolledCourse> StudentEnrolledCourses { get; set; }
```

the controller for edit is also here

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "StudentId,StudentName,StudentEmail,StudentContactNo,RegistrationDate,Address,DepartmentId,RegistrationNumber")] Student student)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(student).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName", student.DepartmentId);
    return View(student);
}
```

what can be done for this problem?

Comment: Why not make StudentEmail unique in the database, instead of relying on code to do so?

Comment: According to  best practice is it better to create separate DTO for edit. Like StudentForUpdate. You should add all the fields in the entity, which you want to update.

Comment: StudentEmail is uniquein the the database .thats why cant permit to edit keeping same email .

Comment: what is the meaning of DT0 ,could u explain @Eugene

Comment: DTO  is Data transfer object https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create StudentForUpdate, then your update Action method will looks like

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "StudentId,StudentName,StudentContactNo,RegistrationDate,Address,DepartmentId,RegistrationNumber")] StudentForUpdate student)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(student).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName", student.DepartmentId);
    return View(student);
}
```

In this case, email will never be changed.

Comment: should StudentForUpdate model class  with same property  be created?@eugene

Comment: According to best-practice - Yes, it should. You can create Base Class and derive 2 classes  StudentForCreate and StudentForUpdate. If you do so you can use AutoMapper to map the objects and don't copy all the fields manually between them.

Comment: but when i inherit from base class it also inherit the unique property that would be conflict to add same email just changing other property like name,address@eugene

Comment: Don't add email into Base class. Add it into StudentForCreate  only